# How to not roll back db transactions created in pytest-django fixture of class scope

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I'm using pytest with Django (via [pytest-django](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-django)) and I'm wondering if it's possible to have a fixture of scope `class` that creates some models in the database and then *not* have those models removed at the end of each test.

For example;

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def expensive():
    return MyModel.objects.create()


@pytest.mark.django_db()
class TestMyModel:

    def test_a(self, expensive):
          MyModel.objects.get()  # All good

    def test_b(self, expensive):
          MyModel.objects.get()  # raises MyModel.DoesNotExist
```

This is just a simplified example, in my actual code the fixture `expensive` is actually doing something that takes some time (and I'm actually using a parametrize test but I imagine that won't make any difference). My desire is that the data created in the fixture `expensive` is rolled back once out of the scope of the class so as to not interfere with other tests.

It appears as if what I'm trying to do might be possible using the fixture [django_db_blocker](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#django-db-blocker) however I was not able to get this to behave as I wanted.

Comment: Do you want to roll back the changes after each test or retain it through out the test cycle , the heading of the question says **not rollback** but the test description says > **My desire is that the data created in the fixture expensive is rolled back once out of the scope of the class so as to not interfere with other tests**

Comment: I'd like to retain any transactions that occur in `expensive` while transactions that occur in either of the tests is rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue for the last couple of days and managed to come up with a solution that works in almost all cases. Its kind of hacked together based on the `pytest-django` source. If you add it to a test class make sure to not add any built in `pytest-django` db marks.

```
import psycopg2
from django.apps import apps
from django.test.utils import setup_databases, teardown_databases
# alternatively if you're not on django 1.11 you need
# from pytest_django.compat import setup_databases, teardown_databases

@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def class_scoped_db(django_db_blocker):
    try:
        django_db_blocker.unblock()
        # if test db exists use it and delete all objects once done
        _ = psycopg2.connect(dbname='test_{your_db_name}')
        yield
        # drop all objects created once we are out of scope
        for app_name in {list of your django apps}:
            for model in apps.get_app_config(app_name).get_models():
                model.objects.all().delete()

    except psycopg2.OperationalError:
        # if test db doesn't exist then create one and tear down once done
        db_cfg = setup_databases(verbosity=pytest.config.option.verbose,
                                 interactive=False)
        yield
        teardown_databases(db_cfg, verbosity=pytest.config.option.verbose)

    finally:
        django_db_blocker.restore()
```

The one case I've found in which it doesn't work is when the first test to run that needs db access uses the `class_scoped_db`, I think the teardown method leaves the database connection in a strange state that the remaining tests cannot work with. Works fine for me in a full test run or when testing the individual test class or module